# Displaying a blank website before JavaScript is applied

Tags: javascript

I need the website to display blank before JavaScript is applied, instead of the words "Hello World!". Is there an easy way to do this? Thank you.

```
<div id = "id">
Hello World!
</div>

<script type = "text/javascript">
document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript!";
</script>
```

PS: The above is, of course, just an example, and most of the time it'll display "Hello JavaScript!" so fast that it'll look like "Hello World!" wasn't even there, unless you have a really, really slow internet connection.

Comment: Just delete the Hello World from your DIV

Comment: and put some styles like background: white, in order it do display consistently in every browser

Comment: css: `html{ display: none;} html.done{ display:block;}`  then at end of js: `document.documentElement.className+=" done";`

Comment: This is sometimes referred to as FOUC (flash of unstyled content), and while its nice to prevent FOUC from a UX perspective, there is a usability issue in showing nothing until you reach the javascript as that could be awhile. Best practice would be to indicate some content is coming with [skeleton screens](http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1797) or some other loading indicator.

Comment: @ChrisL Smart. But "Hello World!" is actually there for a reason. That reason being when JavaScript isn't turned off, or when users don't have JavaScript.

Comment: @ChristopherMeyers Another issue would be when users don't have JavaScript, or don't have it turned on. Then, it would just be showing a blank page and confusing users.

Comment: @frosty you are talking about 0.1 - 0.2% of the population not having javascript turned on or a browser that doesn't support JS

Comment: http://breakthewebforward.com/

Comment: @ChrisL My point, is that I would like users to be able to see the contents of my website, whether they have it turned off or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place all your content inside a `#container`, which is hidden by default. Then once you get to your JavaScript show it:

CSS

```
#container { display: none; }
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id = "id">
            Hello World!
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

JS

```
document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript!";
document.getElementById("container").style.display = "block"; // show
```

Comment: Can the container be the <body> of the website too?

Comment: @frosty Yes I believe you can do `<body id="container">` as well. But It's possible that approach would work on less browsers, although I'm not certain on that.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this,

```js
setTimeout(function(){
 document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript!";
},2000)
```

```html
<div id = "id">
  (Pretending its blank)
</div>
```

### OR

```js
document.getElementById("id").style.display = 'none'
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("id").style.display = 'block'
 document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript!";
},2000)
```

```html
<div id = "id">
  Hello World!
</div>
```

Comment: If the div is blank you don't need the setTimeout and if it weren't blank this would not accomplish what the question was asking. Additionally, there is no way to predict how long it will take the javascript to load so you will be picking an arbitrary length of time to make everyone wait for the page to load for no reason at all instead of providing immediate content to those with good internet connections

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just set the default style of whatever element you're trying to hide to `display: none` in your CSS. Then add something like the following to your JS or your document in script tags...

```
    window.onload = function () { 
      // Do stuff what you need
      var elToShow = document.getElementById('id_of_element');

      // Then show the content that was not displayed
      elToShow.style.display = 'block'; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a CSS class to hide the content:

```
<style>
.hidden { display: none; }
</style>
```

Add the class to the div:

```
<div id = "id" class="hidden">
   Hello World!
</div>
```

Update the JavaScript to assign the text content and unhide the **div** by removing the class when the page finishes loading.

```
<script>
    var idDiv = document.getElementById("id");
    idDiv.textContent = "Hello JavaScript!";
    window.addEventListener("load",function(){
        idDiv.className = idDiv.className.replace(/hidden/,'');
    });
</script>
```